# Sonar CAS Integration - Getting error as "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Tags: sonarqube, cas

While configuring CAS with Sonar 3.7 am getting the error as follows:

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty

I have installed CAS Plugin and have added below in sonar.prperties file:

> sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true sonar.security.realm=cas
>   sonar.cas.protocol=cas2
>   sonar.cas.casServerLoginUrl=http://www.xxx.com:8443/cas/login
>   sonar.cas.sonarServerUrl=http://www.xxx.com:9000

Please help me in solving the issue.Am not able to integrate CAS with sonar 3.7.
What is the solution or is there any other way to SSO sonar with CAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most often occurs when the SSL cert of the CAS server isn't trusted by the CAS client server, in this case Sonar. Assuming Sonar is running on Tomcat, you'll want to add the CAS server's cert to the Tomcat server's java install cacerts file ({JAVA_HOME}\lib\security\cacerts).

Comment: if am using normal jetty server then?

Comment: I can't answer definitively, but it most likely uses the Java cacerts file. In my experience, it is the J2EE servers that utilize their own trust stores.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the CAS plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/CAS+Plugin, it was deprecated a long time ago and is not compatible with SonarQube 3.7.

Comment: aNY OTHER WAY TO CAS integrate ??

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post for integrate cas with SonarQube 3.7+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420688

Or you can try my fork which also supports LDAP user name, email and group import.

https://github.com/kzhang7/sonar-cas