# How to integrate CAS authentification in SonarQube

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, sonarqube, cas

we want to integrate CAS authentication into Sonar 3.7 LTS. We want to start working with the deprecated CAS plugin, which of course doesn't work. We already compared it with the LDAP plugin from [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/LDAP+Plugin) whose Authenticator interestingly implements the deprecated interface `LoginPasswordAuthenticator`. One of the main differences is that the CAS Authenticator plugin implements `Authenticator`. So we altered the CAS Plugin that it implements `LoginPasswordAuthenticator` instead.

Now comes the clue:
In both cases, the authenticator implementing `Authenticator` or `LoginPasswordAuthenticator`, the username passed to it is `null`. The authentication against the CAS server works like a charm, the plugin knows the username, but Sonar asks the plugin, if it knows the user with the name `null`. The effect is that when we click on login we get redirected to CAS, fill in the login form and get redirected back to Sonar, still not authenticated to Sonar itself.

We also considered using container authentication but are not sure if that works with Sonar.

Now the question(s):

- Has someone got the CAS plugin working with Sonar 3.7? If yes, how and can you provide the sources/solution/plugin?
- Is there another way besides the suggested ones above?

One additional note: We want to use Sonar in our existing Tomcat 7, so using Sonar 4 is a way we do not really want to go because the Sonar team decided to stop war support. If anything else fails though, using it is a pain-in-the-ass-but-acceptable solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @psqita we got the CAS plugin for Sonar up and running with Saml 1.1. Business requirements said that no anonymous access shall be allowed. Sadly, setting `forceAuthentication` to `true` sent us into an endless loop of painful redirecting between CAS and Sonar. So we figured out that Sonar alters its behavior drastically in a way that it ignores all authentication plugins.

Our solution: As of business requirement we could not allow anonymous access. So we implemented another `Filter` that redirects conditionally to CAS. Authentication and stuff is still done by the plugin. Sadly, we still do not know why there was this endless loop in the first place but now it doesn't happen anymore. Well that's IT I think...

Thank you for your support and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fork: https://github.com/jerzykrlk/sonar-cas.

I restored the behaviour of the original plugin - it should work with Sonar 3.7. It is unofficial at the moment, and will require a manual build. But maybe it will become an official plugin at some point, again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tested your library, but after logging in to CAS I get a blank page containing "no" as only message. It happens while validating the service ticket. I have tried using SSL with CAS, using no SSL, deactivating the X509TrustManager with and without SSL. Any ideas? Simply "no" isn't that enlightening...

Comment: There's very few changes compared to the original CAS plugin, so I'd try to play around with configuration, first.

Comment: There's very few changes compared to the original CAS plugin, so I'd try to play around with configuration, first.
 
The original CAS plugin used to work with Sonar up to 3.1, I think. Can you verify the same configuration with Sonar 3.1 and the original plugin Sonar CAS plugin?

And, could you post the configuration here? If I don't find anything now, I will take a closer look on Monday.

Comment: Thank you, we will try to get a Sonar 3.1 up and running with the CAS plugin. I'll let you know if it's configuration works in the new CAS plugin.

Comment: Hi, we got Sonar 3.1 running with the old CAS plugin from here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/CAS+Plugin. Sadly, the same configuration doesn't work with the fork and Sonar 3.7. It still says simply "no". Here is the CAS part of sonar.properties: http://pastebin.com/DjxZuuH2. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I checked your configuration and I have one question: sonar.cas.sonarServerUrl is set to the same IP address as your CAS server. This should be your Sonar's address - are you running Sonar and CAS on the same machine and port?

Comment: I'll be able to review the rest of configuration later and I should be able to give more feedback at the beginning of next week.

Comment: Thank you @psqita, we fixed the URLs. CAS is on the same server as Sonar, but the paths were wrong. With anonymous access allowed it works like a charm but `forceAuthentication` needs to be `true`, so no anonymous access. Sadly, when logging in to CAS we end up in an endless loop between the paths `/cas/login`, `/sonar/cas/validate` and `/sonar/sessions/new` which redirects back to `/cas/login` and so on. Do you still have some ideas?

Comment: Hi again. I have never tried having CAS and Sonar on the same machine. I used to have session-related problems with Sonar. Can you try using different machines, hostnames or IPs? And, if this fails, try setting `RackFilter`'s property `resetUnhandledResponse` to `false` - see [https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack#rails](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack#rails) - `<filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>` section for details.